# QProcess state() always returns RUNNING

Tags: qt

I do the following to start a process and waits for its completion (I am intentionally avoiding use of SIGNAL/SLOTS in this case).

```
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
QString program = "test.exe";
QStringList args;
myProcess->start(program, args);
myProcess->waitForStarted();

while( myProcess->state() == QProcess::Running )
{
    // Do other things...
}
```

I can verify that test.exe exits. But process state is for some reason always QProcess::Running. I am using Qt 4.8.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "do other things" does not include processing events of the thread's event loop, then the `QProcess` never gets a chance to update its `state`.

Either `waitForFinished` if this needs to block the thread or connect to the `finished()` signal.

Comment: Adding a proc->waitForFinished(1); in the while looped fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `state()` should be used to check for a program that has closed down but you can use something like [`while(!waitForFinished(1))`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#waitForFinished).